# Why is there a seemingly big difference in power supply input and output watts?

Tags: power-supply, power

Looking at a power supply like:
[image: Corsair AX 860W Power Supply]
I notice there seems to be a big difference between the AC input watts(240V x 5.5A = **1320W**) and DC output watts (**860W**)

I read on [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1164933/1237653) that Virtually all power supplies are now 80-90% efficient, but the way I calculated, this power supply is only about 65.15% effective (860/1320=0,65151).

I noticed a similar but worse thing with my Lenovo IdeaPad3 Laptop Power supply:

| Power | Volts | Amps | Watts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AC input | 240V | 1.7A | 408W |
| DC output | 20V | 3.25A | 65W |
|  |  | Efficiency | **16%** |

Why are there differences?

Comment: You might be better off posting this on our dedicated electronics site [electronics.se] than here.

Comment: I am not sure how you figure this. I have numerous Lenovo adapters and none of them use 400 watts of power. I have measured with a good Wattmeter. Remember that rating is not the same as usage. The AC side needs to withstand a temporary surge in  the DC side.

Comment: Their AC input may be across a 100-250V range, with the 1.7A being the peak draw at the lowest voltage. As the voltage goes up the current drawn will decrease. That said there is still some disparity but I cant see what devices you have.

Comment: Another issue is AC power factor, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_factor. For example, a perfect 4 µF capacitor across a 240 VAC, 60 Hz mains would allow a current of about 0.36 amperes to flow -- yet dissipate *no* power whatsoever, because current is out of phase with voltage. That discussion belongs at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/, though.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading the 860 from only one power rail, not the total power output.

For your power supply it is not "just" 860W output it is

| Volts | Amps | Watts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| +3.3V | 25A | 125W |
| +5 | 25A | 125W |
| +12 | 71A | 852W |
| -12 | 0.5A | 6W |
| +5Vsb | 3A | 15W |
|  | **Total** | **1123W** |
|  |  |  |
| **Input** |  |  |
| 240V | 5.5A | **1320W** |

and  1152W / 1320W = 0.87 == 87%

<sub>(In theory 3.3V @ 25A is 87.5W, but they may be doing some weird math. Their manual is vague in that regard)</sub>

So your power supply is *potentially* 87% efficient.

You cannot take only one rail out and say that is the total power. The 860 in the product designation is a marketing number denoting their "peak" power assuming that all power is drawn from a single high power rail, the 12V rail. The actual power shown on the table is when power is drawn across all rails.

The rating of both input and output takes account of absolute peak draw, not just one single rail.

The reason they're giving you the 12V rail as the "product number" is because normally that is where the most power is drawn in modern computers. The CPU has its own power regulators which go from 12V down to the CPU voltage at anywhere up to 200W for modern CPUs, and the graphics card dows the same and draws anywhere up to 400-600W at the high end.

With just those two figures if you have a top end CPU and GPU you can quickly see that both the 860W or 760W (12V rail) PSU would be fine your system.

Comment: Thanks, for the solid answer clearing that up.
This does not explain why my Lenovo AC Adapter/Power supply seems so ineffiecient (and I saw the same on phone chargers and other smaller AC Adapters). Care to quess the reason for that mismatch? Is it because current rating is always for breaker load rating?

Comment: I suspect with the smaller power bricks they are listing the peak inrush current as the power supply starts up. I just checked one of my USB PD charger and it say 1.2A @100V (120W) for a 45W output and all I can think of is that there will be an initial burst of 1.2A as capacitors charge up and inductor coils energise, after that it will settle down. They're listing the worst case, not the ongoing current.

Comment: I also forgot to say, for the computer PSU the 860 is the "normal/safe" power draw, while the maximums and total draw will be "absolute limits" which will only be allowed for short durations. It *could* supply 1123W for brief periods (and so draw 5.5A) but things may overheat, components may be under stress and other things may happen. 860 is the constant safe and sustained power draw they expect. I should rephrase that bit in my answer.